# Query List of DateTime objects between hours

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a list of DateTime Objects, this objects have a StarteDate and a EndDate. No I want to get all items that occur within a StartHour and an EndHour.

My code so far:

```
var sameDay  = allItems.Where(x => x.Start.Date == calendarItem.StartDate.Date 
                            && x.Start.Hour >= startHour && x.End.Hour <= endHour);
```

This works as long as the start hor of an item is equal or larger than the startHour provided. However if for example the startHour = 09:00 and an item has Start = 8:00 and End = 10:00 it is ignored.

How can I include items that have a start hour between start hour and end hour?

Thank you!

Comment: You are comparing date with `calendarItem`, while `startHour` and `endHour` are standalone. Could you post more code?

Comment: What is your value for endHour? I.e. does (x.End.Hour <= endHour) equal true?

Comment: sorry, calendarItem.StartDate is a provided instance. But for this example it could also new = new Datetime(2014, 06, 05).

Comment: What you want to return exactly, the items that either started or end between your startHour and endHour? or you want something else?

Comment: No, all items that fall within the range. For example if my StartHour = 09:00 and one items has startHour = 08:00 and endhour = 10 i like to have this item included. If an item starts at 07:00 and ends at 08:00 i dont like to have it included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sameDay = allItems.Where(x => x.Start.Date == calendarItem.StartDate &&
    (((x.Start.Hour >= startHour && x.Start.Hour < endHour) ||
    (x.End.Hour > startHour && x.End.Hour <= endHour)) ||
    (x.Start.Hour < startHour && x.End.Hour > endHour)));
```

Check to see if either the start of the event is in the time window, or the end of the event is in the time window, or whether the event overlaps the time window. (Added a fix to prevent inclusive end and start times)

Testing some more, it can be shrunk to this:

```
var sameDay = allItems.Where(x => x.Start.Date == calendarItem.StartDate &&
    (x.Start.Hour < endHour && x.End.Hour > startHour));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works :

```
var sameDay  = allItems.Where(x => x.Start.Date == calendarItem.StartDate.Date 
                        && x.Start.Hour >= startHour && x.Start.Hour <= endHour);
```

Comment: if one condition is not met, it will fail. OP's failing example will also fail here (Start.Hour is smaller than startHour)

Comment: the question is that "How can I include items that have a start hour between start hour and end hour?", I am not sure if Peter wants some other result.

Comment: `No I want to get all items that occur within a StartHour and an EndHour.`